# how to get annotation according to Incident Guid

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to retrieve all Annotations/notes (vanila field in Incident entity) to use in my plugin according to specific Incident Guid. I can't find the "field" to use in columnset and examples online shows retrieve Annotation/notes according to Annotation Guid and not according to Incident Guid.

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field is `objectid`

```
var query = new QueryExpression("annotation") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)};
query.Criteria.AddCondition("objectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, [IncedentGuid]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("annotation")
    {
        Criteria = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.FilterExpression()
        {
            Conditions =
            {
                new ConditionExpression("objectid",ConditionOperator.Equal,incidentGuid)
            }
        },
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
    };
```